# how to load CSS file into jsp

Tags: java, jsp-tags

I created a jsp page as follows:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/css" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login page</title>
<link href="/css/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1> India welfare</h1>
<p> welcome </p>
</body>
</html>
```

and named it as **login.jsp**

and i also created a css file called loginstyle.css and the code of the .css file is as follows:

```
body
{
background-color:#d0e4fe;
}
h1
{
color:orange;
text-align:center;
}
p
{
font-family:"Times New Roman";
font-size:20px;
}
```

the directory structure for css and jsp's are as follows:
**webcontent/welfare_web/css** for .css files  and
**webcontent/welfare_web/login** for jsp files

the programming editor is **eclipse** and the server i am using is **tomcat 7.0**. when i am trying to run the login.jsp file using tomcat server. The css file is not showing any effect. i mean the output is normal text and is not as per the CSS file.

please help me how to make the .css file to effect the jsp file.

Answer (score 35):

css href link is incorrect. Use relative path instead:

```
<link href="../css/loginstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 33):

I use this version

```
<style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/css/style.css"%></style>
```

Answer (score 32):

You can write like that. This is for whenever you change context path you don't need to modify your jsp file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/styles.css" />
```

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem too. Then i realized that **in the MainPageServlet the urlPatterns parameter in @WebServlet annotation contained "/"**, because i wanted to forward to the MainPage if the user entered the section *www.site.com/* . When i tried to open the css file from the browser, the url was www.site.com/css/desktop.css, but the page content was THE PAGE *MainPage.jsp*. So, i removed the "/" urlPattern and now i can use CSS files in my jsp file using one of the most common solutions (`${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/desktop.css`).
Make sure  your servlet doesn't contain the "/" urlPattern.
I hope this worked for u too,
- Axel Montini

Answer (score 2):

if everything seems correct, and despite it still does not work I invite you to load the statics files in the web.xml like this

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/includes/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

after

```
<!-- bootstrap css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/includes/asserts/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this it worked for me

```
   <style><%@include file="/WEB-INF/view/style/style.css"%></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSS :

```html
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

For JS :

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Files location:

```bash
└───src
    └───main
        ├───java
        └───webapp
            ├───css/bootstrap.css
            ├───js/bootstrap.js
            ├───META-INF
            └───WEB-INF/index.jsp
                └───lib
```

[image: css-js file location JSP]