# issue with css mime type with jsp and tomcat

Tags: css, jsp, tomcat, mime-types, mime

I have an issue with my jsp project running on tomcat. Website looks css file like html and it doesn't load them. Resources are correctly retrieved because with inspect i see 200 ok code for css files. I run my project on Tomcat 8.0. Code is following:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml -->
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Project</display-name>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>css</extension>
    <mime-type>text/css</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**HomepageServlet**

```
package webapp;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/", "/Homepage"})
public class HomepageServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute("name", request.getParameter("name"));
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/views/Homepage.jsp").forward(request, response);       
    }
}
```

**Homepage.jsp**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Project!!</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="navbar-menu">
      <div class="navbar-menu-row">
        <div class="navbar-menu-first-row">
          <img src="images/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Project's structure is following:

https://image.ibb.co/k9vj5K/Immagine.png

What is it wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should check if browser is ok with mime type of the css file. Standard behaviour is not to add this information by tomcat. You may proxy this through apache http server or create a filter which will add mime type to css and js files and put it in response headers. Older browsers were not this strict in checking but it may cause security issues if some things will be interpreted just by filename.

Comment: In **web.xml** you specified a mime type of **text/csss**. Did you mean to specify **text/css** instead?

Comment: I try to use many browser like firefox, chrome and IE but nothing. Furthermore i try to use GlassFish Server 4.1 instead Tomcat, but result is the same. I also correct text/ccs instead text/csss, issue has not been resolved. I'm thinking to use python flask instead jsp because i'm going crazy!

Comment: @Raul [1] But **text/ccs** is also invalid! Set it to **text/css**. [2] To be clear, is your application working OK, except that your CSS stylesheet is not being used? [3] Also, your path for the CSS file may be incorrect, though I don't know how you have structured your project. See if the SO question [how to load CSS file into jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7382607/2985643) helps you. [4] As a separate issue please note that when replying to comments you should start your comment with @{userId} (as I have done for this comment), so that the other user is notified of your reply.

Comment: @skomisa [1] typing error sorry! i set text/css. [2] application working ok, only css and js are not loaded. [3] I try many different solutions, but only <%@ include file="css/style.css"%> works. It is not what i would like because i should put files in WEB-INF folder. [4] Thanks for your suggestion ;)

Comment: @Raul OK. Please update your post (rather than putting the information in a comment) to specify the structure of your project, especially with respect to your **css** and **js** files. I don't see any mention of **js** files in your question.

Comment: @skomisa. I updated projecte's structure in the post. Thank you.

Comment: @Raul Your project structure shows that your JSP is in **WEB-INF/views/Homepage.jsp**, yet the servlet redirects to **/views/Homepage.jsp**, which is incorrect. The redirect should be to **WEB-INF/views/Homepage.jsp** instead, so I don't understand how the code you have posted can work for that project structure. Are you certain that the source files and the project structure you have posted are all up to date, or is there something I am not understanding?

Comment: @skomisa Sorry skomisa but before and after i created this post i tried many different solutions, like changing project structure, using relative path for file css, etc.